# how to clear and/or disable nx remote cache

Tags: package.json, nrwl

Sometimes I removes my `dist` folder to make sure I will not run old code. I noticed that `nx` caches build results. This means that `nx` does nothing when nothing has changed, meaning my `dist` directory remains empty after a build.

What I remove the cache

```
$> npm cache clean --force && rimraf ./node_modules/.cache/nx
```

I think that `nx reset` might works too instead, but this works as well!

However, when I run my build job again it still uses cache:

```
> nx run build  [remote cache] 

>  NX   Successfully ran target build for project docker (939ms)

   Nx read the output from the cache instead of running the command for 1 out of 1 tasks.
```

The only way I can make sure it rebuild is

```
$> nx run build  --skip-nx-cache
```

But I'm not sure how to do this with `npm` though

```
$> npm build -- --skip-nx-cache
```

doesn't work, because it will add the `--skip-nx-cache` to all underlying commands.

Anyway, the main problem in my case is `[remote cache]`. I don't know anything about remote cache. How does this work? and most of all, how can I disable this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try setting an environment variable:

```bash
NX_SKIP_NX_CACHE=true nx run build
```